# Order of the main set $A$ is greater than 10?

Tags: group-theory

> A group $G$, acting on a set $A$, is a permutation group such that it has an element of order $30$. Prove that order of $A$ is greater than $10$.

Here, I supposed that, $|A|=6$ and wanted to make a contradiction. The possible order of group $G$ could be $30$, $60$, $120$, $240$, $360$ and $720$. And I supposed $|x|=30$ is that element in $G$. If $|G|=30$ so $G$ be an abelian group, it acts on $A$ transitively so $(G|A)$ is regular and then $|G|=|A|$ which is wrong. The same way could be carried out when $|G|=60$. If $|G|=360$, we would face to contradiction because $A_{6}$ is simple. Honestly, I could not go for the rest. Have I been on a right way? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\sigma$ be the element of order $30$. Decompose $\sigma$ into disjoint cycles. Since $|\sigma| = 30$, the L.C.M. of the number of elements in each cycle is $30$. Considering that $30 = 2 \times 3 \times 5$, what can you conclude?

Comment: Cause 30=2*3*5, so the cardinal of $A$ is least 10?

Comment: Think of the different possibilities of the structure of $\sigma$ as disjoint cycles: for example, $\sigma$ might contain a cycle of $30$ elements. If that's the case, then $|A| \geq 30 > 10$. Or maybe $\sigma$ contains a $2$-cycle and a $15$-cycle, in which case $|A| \geq 17 > 10$. What other possibilities are there?

Comment: It seems to me that the "greater than" in the statement of the problem ought to be "greater than or equal to".

Comment: @Gerry: Yes, without doubt.